# Xcode automatically choosing an invalid team

Tags: ios, xcode, account, iphone-developer-program

I'm working on an existing iOS project that was setup on a team external from my own. In the target's general settings, I'm trying to change the team from the existing "Unknown Team" team to "None", but it keeps automatically switching back to "Unknown Team" when the dropdown closes.

Is there a way to manually set the team, rather than using Xcode's obviously buggy team dropdown?

I've never had a problem switching between teams before, but I also haven't had to switch from a team that I didn't own, either.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to manually change the team. If you open the `project.pbxproj` file as plain text, you can search for `DevelopmentTeam =` and delete the enclosing dictionary inside `Target Attributes` (the key should be a random hash).

This will set the team to None.

However, if there is a better way to do this, I'd like to know - manually editing the `.pbxproj` is really a rough way to go about doing this.